# Python program Airnef stuck while downloading images

Tags: python, macos, wifi, photography

I am using [Airnef](http://testcams.com/airnef/) to download pictures from my Canon DSLR camera through python.

I can download one picture without problems so the whole setup seems to work. However, as soon as I want to download another image the software hangs. The code to me looks quite complex.

Two months ago I did post [a thread](http://testcams.com/blog/forums/topic/only-first-image-downloaded-from-canon-camera/#post-9694) on TestCams.com. Since I haven't gotten a response, I post this as a python-related question here.

### The thread

I start airnef from the command line.

```
python airnefcmd.py --ipaddress 192.168.188.84 --action getfiles --realtimedownload only --downloadexec open @pf@ --transferorder newestfirst --outputdir "/Users/besi/Desktop"
```

I connect the camera and I’m shown some information about my connection:

> Connection established to 192.168.188.84:15740
>   Camera Model “Canon EOS 200D”, S/N “XXXXXXXXX”

Now airnef tells me:

> Waiting for realtime photos from camera to download.
>   Press  to exit |

I take a picture and it downloads it as expected:

> Downloading “IMG_0084.JPG”: 96%

Airnef then shows some more information about this image:

> /Users/besi/Desktop/IMG_0084.JPG [size = 4,602,357] in 1.94 seconds (2.26 MB/s)

I take some more pictures but they’re not downloaded and the software is stuck at the prompt:

> Waiting for realtime photos from camera to download. Press  to exit \

### Source code

The source code is available at the Airnef Website. I created a github repository for tackling this issue: https://github.com/besi/airnef

The place where the code is stuck is at [airnefcmd.py:3203](https://github.com/besi/airnef/blob/master/airnefcmd.py#L3202-L3204)

#### Update: Forum Post

Here is the link to the [forum post on testcams.com](http://testcams.com/blog/forums/topic/only-first-image-downloaded-from-canon-camera/#post-9719)

#### Update: Debugging

The first image called IMG_0182 [was downloaded](https://gist.github.com/besi/4183f033241bc0249d204236c54ba195#file-airnef-log-L294-L299)  successfully.

In the debug output I can see a new picture being taken, but the download is skipped because the prior image was already downloaded:

See [airnef.log:433](https://gist.github.com/besi/4183f033241bc0249d204236c54ba195#file-airnef-log-L433-L439):

```
    filename           = DCIM\100CANON\IMG_0183.JPG
    captureDateSt      = 20180926T071759
    modificationDateStr= 20180926T071758
```

A new image called `IMG_0183.JPG` was found.

```
Skipping IMG_0182.JPG - already downloaded this session
```

The old downloaded image seems to block the further processing of the current image.

```
Skipping 100CANON - object is not file - MTP_OBJFORMAT_Assocation (0x3001)
Skipping DCIM - object is not file - MTP_OBJFORMAT_Assocation (0x3001)
Waiting for realtime photos from camera to download. Press <ctrl-c> to exit -execMtpOp: MTP_OP_GetObjectHandles - CmdReq payload:
```

Now we end up again in the loop waiting for more pictures.
When a new picture is taken, the same procedure happens again.

Comment: Dumb question: are there any other **realtime** photos on the camera? Or it just waits for one to be taken?

Comment: Also, are the times on computer and camera synchronized?

Comment: @CristiFati: It‘s always like this. I start the session. All is good and conneced. I take a picture. It‘s downloaded onto my Desktop. I take several more pictures but they‘re not downloaded. The times are in sync. For testing I did take pictures of http://time.is in my browser.

Comment: What if you take pics one by one (wait between them)? Also after the 1st pic is taken, the times stay in sync (no different timezones, etc)? *open* is an executable? (based on paths I assume you're on *OSX*).  `--downloadexec` would be normally at the end (how does it know when the args for the executable are over, and the next one should be processed?, or enclosed in quotes?). Did you try dropping it (or others) to see if anything changes? Is the 1st file open after download? Note: I've never worked with *airnef*, sorry for (maybe) giving you false hope.

Comment: @CristiFati: The parameters I‘m using seem fine because the first image is downloaded and opened. Yes `open ` is a command on macOS. It is equivalent to a double click in the Finder (Explorer). So the images are simply opened once they‘re downloaded.

Comment: Apparently, when trying to download the 2nd picture, it sees the 1st one, and then ignores everything. Not sure whether it's a bug, or smth related to your camera, you could play with some parameters: `--downloadhistory ignore` (it might download each file multiple times), or `--rtd_mtppollingmethod_newobjdetection numobjs`, or as a workaround figure a way to delete a file on the camera once it's downloaded.

Comment: @CristiFati: The `numobjs` parameter in conjunction with `--transferorder oldestfirst` did the trick. You may add an answer which I will happily accept.

Comment: So this is the lucky combo? Neither of the 2 args doesn't do the trick alone? Smth seems "fishy" :).

Comment: @CristiFati: Actually the default for `transferorder` is `oldestfirst`. So while it's true the `rtd_mtppollingmethod_newobjdetection` flag does fix the problem, but once `newestfirst` is enabled then this no longer works. That means it is indeed the lucky combo. It's likely that this is a bug, which I did point out in the [testcams forum](http://testcams.com/blog/forums/topic/only-first-image-downloaded-from-canon-camera/#post-9725)

Comment: I followed the forum (I looked at the message exchange and noticed the current behavior). Also, I've noticed that *oldestfirst* is the default for realtime: https://github.com/besi/airnef/blob/master/airnefcmd.py#L3403. So, if `--transferorder` is not specified at all, it should work as well. The reason of me asking is I'm trying to narrow down the problem as much as possible, and unfortunately I don't have a camera (I have an ancient Canon S5 IS which definitely isn't supported) to test it myself with.

Comment: @CristiFati: "So, if --transferorder is not specified at all, it should work as well": This is correct. With the debug enabled and the `transferorder` set to `newestfirst` I did see the new images being listed in the output but they were not transferred (See my updated question).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180958/discussion-between-besi-and-cristifati).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a compatible camera, so I'm basing my answer solely on the logs (in *Debug* mode) posted on the forum. 
Also it was a trial and error suggestion in one of the comments, so it's not the "scientific" approach (where the cause is being identified, and then fixed). 
A team (@Besi and I) effort was required in order to come up with this answer (and the credit should be split accordingly).

According to logs, there is a difference between how the 2 files are handled:

> ```
> ...
>
> filename = DCIM\100CANON\IMG_0182.JPG
> captureDateSt = 20180926T071747
> modificationDateStr= 20180926T071748
> Download history file “/Users/besi/Library/Application Support/airnef/appdata/Canon EOS 200D-SN59074c1578e347a3bf1f6f85e8dec624-downloadhist” loaded – 53 entries
> >> MTP_OP_GetObject
> Downloading “IMG_0182.JPG”: 0%IMG_0182.JPG – downloading next piece, offset=0x0, count=0x100000
>
> ...
>
> filename = DCIM\100CANON\IMG_0183.JPG
> captureDateSt = 20180926T071759
> modificationDateStr= 20180926T071758
> Skipping IMG_0182.JPG – already downloaded this session
> Skipping 100CANON – object is not file – MTP_OBJFORMAT_Assocation (0x3001)
> Skipping DCIM – object is not file – MTP_OBJFORMAT_Assocation (0x3001)
> Waiting for realtime photos from camera to download. Press <ctrl-c> to exit -execMtpOp: MTP_OP_GetObjectHandles – CmdReq payload:
>
> ...
> ```

As seen when handling the 2<sup>nd</sup> file (*IMG_0183.JPG*), the existence of the 1<sup>st</sup> one (*IMG_0182.JPG*), triggers everything to be abandoned.

Browsing [[TestCams]: airnef - Wireless download from your Nikon Camera!](http://www.testcams.com/airnef), one of the command line argument (actually, there were more that I suggested) caught my eye: 
***--rtd_mtppollingmethod_newobjdetection***, and I suggested specifying *numobjs* (and thus, overriding the default). Apparently, this was the (main) problem. 
The other part was the presence of ***--transferorder newestfirst***. By default, in **Realtime Download** mode, it's set to *oldestfirst* (see below). Removing it (or redundantly specifying ***--transferorder oldestfirst***) did the trick.

**Conclusion**

In order to fix the problem, 2 things were necessary (in terms of *cmdline* *arg*s for *airnefcmd.py*):

- Specify *--rtd_mtppollingmethod_newobjdetection numobjs*
- Remove *--transferorder newestfirst*

According to [[GitHub]: besi/airnef - (master) airnef/airnefcmd.py#3403](https://github.com/besi/airnef/blob/master/airnefcmd.py#L3403):

```
g.args['transferorder'] = 'oldestfirst'     # so that downloadMtpFileObjects() will properly enumerate through multiple realtime images as we add them
```

I consider this a bug on *airnef*'s side (regarding *--transferorder*). It's located in either

- Code: *--transferorder* should be ignored when in *Realtime* mode
- *Doc*: Specify that *--transferorder newestfirst* is not compatible with *Realtime* mode

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your gift!!! I also want to mention that I didn't do it for the points :) .